# how to change the colours based on role in leaflet open street maps

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

```
var locations = [{ name:"bus", latitude:"12.56", longitude:"25.15, role: "traveler" },
                 { name:"bike", latitude:"13.56", longitude:"25.15, role: "traveler" },
                 { name:"John", latitude:"14.56", longitude:"25.15, role: "Developer" },
                 { name:"David", latitude:"12.56", longitude:"25.15, role: "Developer" },
                 { name:"Mango", latitude:"13.56", longitude:"25.15, role: "Fruit" },
                 { name:"Apple", latitude:"12.56", longitude:"25.15, role: "Fruit" }]



var map = L.map('mapid').setView([locations[0].latitude, locations[0].longitude], 8);
mapLink =
'<a href="#">ABC Corporation</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
   'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink,
    maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.marker([locations[i].latitude,locations[i].longitude])
    .bindPopup(locations[i].name)
    .addTo(map);

}
```

This is my code I want to change the colour of the marker as per the role, right now if add two records with same latitude and longitude, I am able to see only latest one. how can I see the other marker also

Answer (score 0):

For your first question "Change color":

You can't change the color of a marker but you can replace the default Icon, with another Icon.
https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',

    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new L.marker([locations[i].latitude,locations[i].longitude],{icon: greenIcon})
    .bindPopup(locations[i].name)
    .addTo(map);

}
```

To see both Markers on the same point, you can use a spiderfy Library, like: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet or https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Comment: You can use img filtering in CSS to change the colour of icons.

Comment: This handy calculator shows you how - https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Comment: Yes I know that this works, but this is not a good/nice way. Your calculator is only working with black, but the default marker is blue. For me this is more try & error then codeing.

Comment: I'll post an answer with bits of the code I use - I start with a divicon.

Answer (score 0):

From my code - function to return an icon with a colour selected by 'feature.properties.service':

```
function busservice(feature) {
  var service = feature.properties.service;
    var html = '<img class="arrow' + service +'" src="arrow-up-icon-29566.png">'     
    return new L.DivIcon({
        iconSize: 40,
         html: html});

    }
```

and some CSS - a yellow icon for '26' -

```
img.arrow26 {
    filter: invert(96%) sepia(50%) saturate(7493%) hue-rotate(1deg) brightness(102%) contrast(101%);
}
```